# How to send Wordpress article data to an external API during publishing

Tags: wordpress

I'm new to Wordpress and I have to do the following: on publishing a new article on Wordpress I also want to trigger an "event" that takes the article data (text, images, etc.) and sends them to an external API (HTTP post request).

I found some plugins (e.g. wpgetapi.com) that should allow calling an external API but in my understanding, it's more to GET data from an external API to build a Wordpress article. Instead, I need to send article data to an external API.

Where can I put some custom logic to call an external API?
How can I intercept the "publishing event" so that I can populate the API call?

Additional info:

- WordPress version: 6.3.2
- The API exposes a REST operation (PUT) and I have to pass a JSON body

Answer (score 1):

There are a few plugins that can help you to do this, such as:

- WP Webhooks
- AutomatorWP

Once you have installed and activated one of these plugins, you can use it to create a custom logic that is hooked to the publish_post action.

---

You could also use something like [Zapier](https://zapier.com/apps/wordpress/integrations/webhook), to create a "Zap" that triggers a POST request to an external API when a new article is published

---

If you don't want to use a plugin, you can also add your own custom code to intercept the publishing event and send the article data to the external API.

Example:

```
function send_article_data_to_external_api($post_id) {
  // Get the article data.
  $article_data = array(
    'title' => get_the_title($post_id),
    'content' => get_the_content($post_id),
    'images' => get_attached_media('image', $post_id),
  );

  // Make a POST request to the external API.
  // ...
}

// Hook the function to the `publish_post` action.
add_action('publish_post', 'send_article_data_to_external_api');
```

Comment: wow it seems exactly what I want, thanks! I'll try it and I'll come back to share my experience